# Elements don't show up on Dialog

Tags: c++, qt5, qdialog

I am trying to implement a Dialog using QT. This is my first time to write down a Dialog instead of using the designer. This is because this dialog will have some fields which will depend on some selections to appear or not.

I following this guide so far but using it for my own Fields:
https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405224

Somehow my Elements (the LineEdit and Lable) do not appear on the Dialog when I run the application.
I don't get what I am actually missing. Do I need to add the Elements to the Dialog on code somehow?

Here is my header file:

```
    #ifndef PLANETARYVIEW_H
    #define PLANETARYVIEW_H
    #include <QDialog>
    #include <QVBoxLayout>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <QLineEdit>
    #include <QComboBox>

    class PlanetaryView : public QDialog

    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit PlanetaryView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    private:
        QVBoxLayout* PlanetsVLayout;
        QLabel* PlanetLabel;
        QLineEdit* PlanetLineEdit;
   };

   #endif // PLANETARYVIEW_H
```

And that is my cpp file

```
   #include "planetaryview.h"

       PlanetaryView::PlanetaryView(QWidget *parent)
       :QDialog(parent)
  {
       PlanetsVLayout = new QVBoxLayout();

       PlanetLineEdit = new QLineEdit();
       PlanetsVLayout->addWidget(PlanetLineEdit);

       PlanetLabel = new QLabel("Planet:");
       PlanetLabel->setBuddy(PlanetLineEdit);
       PlanetsVLayout->addWidget(PlanetLabel);

  }
```

Idea is to have the Lable and the LineEdit sitting next to each other in the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the layout is not assigned to a widget, the solutions are

```cpp
PlanetsVLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
```

or

```cpp
PlanetsVLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
setLayout(PlanetsVLayout);
```